# Check if value in one table is present in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this is probably easy but I haven't been able to find the right method for it. I have 2 models. One called monitor, and one called follower.

In 'monitor' I have a column called owner_id.

In 'follower' I have a column called follower_id.

What I would like to do is check if any of these match up (I'd like to get a count, not a boolean output). Both belongs_to Users.

How do I go about doing this?

**Situation**

I am trying to calculate a conversion rate from Twitter. Where the follower and the follower ids are the users who is following your account.

On the monitor I let you monitor keyword and interactions, where I save the owner_id (the person you're communicating with).

Now I count all the conversations you have had. Then I want to see how many of those that have turned into following your company.

I have a model called campaigns where you can monitor certain keywords.

```
<% @campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
  <%= campaign.keyword %>
<% end %>
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :alerts
end
```

now what I want to do is track the conversion rate for that specific campaign.

```
 ( CODE HERE*  / campaign.alerts.count ) * 100
```

where CODE HERE* should be the count of how many that exists between :

```
campaign.alerts.map(&:owner_id)
```

and

```
current_user.followers.map(&:follower_id)
```

Comment: show some code or where you are trying to implement it.

Comment: I've added some proper example,  does that help?

Comment: You can do `campaign.alerts.size` to get the number of alerts present for a particular campaign

Answer (score 0):

so what you are trying to do is just to compare two big arrays of ids (`campagin.alerts.map(&:owner_id)` and `current_user.followers.map(&:follower_id)`) and count how many ids are the same, you can use count and count everything that your block expression evaluates as true, and save that on a variable that you will use on your division, something like this:

`result = (campagin.alerts.map(&:owner_id).count do |id|
   current_user.followers.map(&:follower_id)).include?(id)
end`

```
( result  / campaign.alerts.count ) * 100
```

There are many other ways like using Array#all or other methods, maybe you can look at them here and see what fits you most:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D